# Error Throwing not working to how I wanted it

Tags: c++, class, exception, throw

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;

class SampleEx{
    public:
        SampleEx(int, char);
        void setNum(int);
        int getNum();
        void setCh(char);
        char getCh();
    private:
      int number;
      char c;
};

SampleEx :: SampleEx (int n, char c)
{
   this->number =n;
   this->c = c;
}

void SampleEx::setNum(int n){number = n;}
int SampleEx::getNum(){return number;}
void SampleEx::setCh(char n){c = n;}
char SampleEx::getCh(){return c;}

char Read (char[]);
void analyze(char[], int char_loc, int & size);
void DigitProcess(char[], int char_loc, int & size);
void AlphaProcess(char[], int char_loc, int & size);
void printStatus(int status);
int nextSpace(char[], int char_loc, int & size);

int main() {
    int status = 0, char_loc = 0, size = 0;
    char cont = ' ';
    char lexeme[MAX];
    char next = ' ';

    do
    {
        try
        {
            do
            {
                next = Read(lexeme);
                cout << lexeme;
                analyze(lexeme, char_loc, size);
            } while (next !='\n');
        }
        catch (SampleEx &e)
        {
            // cout << "Exception Number: " << e.getNum() << " Char: " << e.getCh() << '\n';
            switch(e.getNum())
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "[Invalid Integer: " << e.getCh() << " Found.] ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "[Invalid Decimal: " << e.getCh() << " Found.] ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "[Invalid Decimal: " << "Too Many . Found.] ";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "[Invalid ID: " << e.getCh() << " Found.] ";
                    break;
            }
        }
        cout << endl << "Continue?  Y] Yes N] No" << endl;
        cin.ignore(size);
        cin >> cont;
        while (cont != 'Y' && cont != 'N')
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input.  Try Again." << endl;
            cin >> cont;
        }
        if (cont == 'Y')
        {
            cin.ignore();
        }
    } while(cont != 'N');
    cout << "Program Ended." << endl;
    return 0;
}

void analyze(char item[], int char_loc, int & size)
{
    SampleEx s1(0, ' ');

    if (isdigit(item[0]))
    {
        DigitProcess(item, char_loc, size);
    }
    else if (isalpha(item[0]))
    {
        AlphaProcess(item, char_loc, size);
    }
    else if (item[0] == '.')
    {
        s1.setCh(item[0]);
        s1.setNum(2);
        throw s1;
    }
    else
    {
        s1.setCh(item[0]);
        s1.setNum(4);
        throw s1;
    }
}

char Read(char temp[])
{
    char extra;
    int size = 0;
    cin.get(extra);
    while (size < MAX && extra != ' ' && extra != '\n')
    {
        temp[size] = extra;
        cin.get(extra);
        size++;
    }
    temp[size] = '\0';
    return extra;
}

void DigitProcess(char item[], int char_loc, int & size)
{
    SampleEx error(0, ' ');
    size = strlen(item);
    bool decimalMax = false, alphaUsed = false;
    for (char_loc = 1; char_loc < size; char_loc++)
    {
        if (isdigit(item[char_loc]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (isalpha(item[char_loc]))
        {
            error.setCh(item[char_loc]);
            error.setNum(1);
            throw error;
            alphaUsed = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (item[char_loc] == '.')
        {
            if (decimalMax == true)
            {
                error.setCh(item[char_loc]);
                error.setNum(3);
                throw error;
            }
            decimalMax = true; // stops anymore decimals from being entered
        }
        else
        {
            error.setCh(item[char_loc]);
            error.setNum(4);
            throw error;
        }
    }
    if (decimalMax == true && alphaUsed == false)
    {
        printStatus(1);
    }
    else if (decimalMax == false && alphaUsed == false)
    {
        printStatus(2);
    }
}

void AlphaProcess(char item[], int char_loc, int & size)
{
    SampleEx error(0, ' ');
    size = strlen(item);
    bool digitUsed = false, deciUsed = false;
    for (char_loc = 1; char_loc < size; char_loc++)
    {
        if (isalpha(item[char_loc]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (isdigit(item[char_loc]))
        {
            digitUsed = true;
            error.setCh(item[char_loc]);
            error.setNum(4);
            throw error;
            for (int i = char_loc; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (isspace(item[i]))
                {
                    char_loc = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (item[char_loc] == '.')
        {
            deciUsed = true;
            error.setCh(item[char_loc]);
            error.setNum(4);
            throw error;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            error.setCh(item[char_loc]);
            error.setNum(4);
            throw error;
        }
    }
    if (digitUsed == false && deciUsed == false)
    {
        printStatus(3);
    }
}

void printStatus(int status)
{
    switch(status)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Decimal ";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Integer ";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "ID ";
    }
}
```

The above code will give "ID" if I were to say something like x or mike, "Decimal" if I were to say something like 4.4424, "Integer" if I were to say like 444.

However, it will print an error if anything is invalid, like if I put .333, it should print an error.  The issue is that the program refuses to print multiple errors at a time.

For example: if I were to put "taco taco taco", it should print ID ID ID.
but if I were to put taco taco taco1, it would print ID ID [Invalid ID: 1 found]
The problem is that if I were to put taco taco1 taco1, it would NOT print the following:
ID [Invalid ID: 1 found] [Invalid ID: 1 found]

which that is the goal.

Comment: if you want your parsing to continue working simply move your try catch inside your while loop

Comment: Please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)